Structural Mass Fraction
In spacecraft design, when talking about the structural mass fractions, the NASA website gives the following equation:

Source: https://www1.grc.nasa.gov/beginners-guide-to-aeronautics/mass-ratios/
However some sources divide the structural mass by the total mass (i.e. propellant mass + structural mass + payload mass).

Source:  https://sentinelmission.org/rocketry-propulsion-glossary/mass-fraction/
My question is, when should the payload be included and when should it not be included in the calculation of structural mass fractions? Thanks.

What's one of the other sources that use the other definition? Also note that epsilon is defined as the structural coefficient not mass fraction.

Hi I have added a link (in the original post above) to one of the sources that mention the use of total mass in the denominator. I have also seen it being done this way in some lectures.

I'm with Marble, it looks like you've taken two similar but different things and lumped them both into "mass fractions". Use the structural coefficient when it's called for, and use the mass fraction when it's called for. The paragraph right after the one you quoted for the first source has an explanation explicitly stating $\epsilon$ is meant to be a design parameter independent of paylaod mass.
